# Create multiple users(objects) in one curl request

Tags: curl, request

I've made an API that can create multiple users at a time, so i usually check it using curl.

So, to create a single user i can do it like this :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/users/create/ --data 'email=test@test.com&password=12345'
```

How to do the same but to create multiple users?

Comment: Hi, does your API accept an array of emails, objects or something else to create multiple users?

Comment: @MoA hi! yes, it is

Comment: An array of emails/passwords?

Comment: @MoA oops, sorry I didn't get it first. It accepts an array of email/password pairs.

Comment: @MoA I just cannot find the way how to post an array

Comment: I see, it seems at the moment you're sending your request as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Can your API process 'application/json' for your request ?

Comment: @MoA it does, how can I make it?

Comment: That depends on your backend. If it can accept 'application/json', then the body of your POST can easily incorporate an array of objects containing 'email/password', e.g.[ {"email":"test@test.com", "password":"test"}, {"email":....}]